# Updating image in tkinter window with newly made images

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, graphics

I have written a program that simulate orbits of planets around a star, I would like a visualiser to display current planet positions around the star. Since all the planets have their x and y co-ords stored, plotting them on an image is straightforward, but I don't know a good way to update the image and re-display after each simulation step.

Currently I draw the image like so (use the planet position to turn a pixel red)

```
def createwindow():
    img = Image.new( 'RGB', (750,730), "black")
    pixels = img.load()

    for thing in celestials:
        pixels[thing.xpos+375+sun.xpos,thing.ypos+375+sun.xpos]=250,20,20
```

So I have an image which displays the planets quite well, which can be remade after each time the planets move. But how do I display this in a tkinter window?

Is there a way of doing this without using a Photoimage which must be saved and loaded? Or a better way of doing this all together? Maybe assigning each planet a label and drawing them directly on a tkinter black window, updating the position of the label with each simulation step?

All help appreciated

Comment: I _really_ hope that that is your real name :)

Comment: My real name is often the subject of ridicule, so I adopted a more sober pseudonym.

Answer (score 2):

There're many ways to display dynamic content, like moving planets. It depends on whether you prefer working with widgets, pixels, images or graphical primitives.

#### Widgets

If you prefer to move widgets, as you said, you can assign each planet to a `Label`. Then you can place it on a window using [Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm):

```python
yourLabel.place(anchor=CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, x=-100, y=50)
```

That'd put a center of the label to coords (-100,50) relative to its parent center (relx=0.5, rely=0.5). To change the position call `.place()` again with different (x,y) coords.

#### Pixels

To change image pixels at runtime you can use `.blank()`, `.get()` and `.put()` methods of `PhotoImage`. They're not in [TkInter book](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), but you can see them in `help(PhotoImage)` in python console. To set a single pixel (x,y) to color #fa1414 use:

```python
yourPhotoImage.put("{#fa1414}", to=(x,y))
```

The `"{#fa1414}"` argument here is actually a pixels list. Tk can put a rectangular block of pixels in one call. Colors are specified row-by-row, separated by spaces, each row enclosed in curly braces. Block of NxM colors would look like "{C<sub>0,0</sub> C<sub>1,0</sub> ... C<sub>N-1,0</sub>} {C<sub>0,1</sub> C<sub>1,1</sub> ... C<sub>N-1,1</sub>} ... {C<sub>0,M-1</sub> C<sub>1,M-1</sub> ... C<sub>N-1,M-1</sub>}". For example, to put 2x2 pixels to coords (4,6) use:

```python
yourPhotoImage.put("{red green} {#7f007f blue}", to=(4,6))
```

Tk recognizes many [symbolic color names](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/colors.htm) in addition to #rrggbb syntax.

Note that all the changes are displayed right away. You don't need to manually "re-display" images. E.g. if you have a `Label(image=yourPhotoImage)` defined somewhere, it'd display the changes after you modify yourPhotoImage.

#### Images

Also PhotoImage can load images from base64-encoded strings. So, technically, to skip saving/loading a *file*, you can load your image from a *string*, containing base64-encoded .gif or .png (formats [supported natively](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/photo.htm#M4) in Tk):

```python
newimg = PhotoImage(data="R0lGODlhHgAUAPAAAP//AAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAeABQAAAIXhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJZmUgAAOw==")
```

`.put()` also supports base64-strings. For example, if you have planets as images, loaded into base64-strings, you can put them into your image with:

```python
yourPhotoImage.put(base64_mars_image_string, to=(100,50))
```

Finally, if you're using PIL anyway, you can create [PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) from your PIL.Image `img` and use it everywhere Tkinter accepts an image object<sup>[[ref]](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)</sup>

```python
from PIL import ImageTk
photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

#### Graphical primitives

If you want lines or arcs you can also use [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm). It provides a way to put together different widgets, images, texts, graphical primitives, and move them around, or configure interaction with them. A canvas-based planetary system could look like this (python2 syntax):

```python
from Tkinter import *
import math, time

color = ["#fffc00", "#a09991", "#b6b697", "#2c81ca", "#a36447", "#b16811", "#e5ca9d", "#bcdaf2", "#7e96bc", "#d3ac8b"]
size = [20, 4, 7, 7, 5, 15, 13, 9, 9, 4]
start_time = time.time()
def update_positions():
    dt = (time.time() - start_time)*5
    for i in range(len(planets)):
        px, py = 350+35*i*math.cos(dt/(i+1)/size[i]+4*i), 350+35*i*math.sin(dt/(i+1)/size[i]+4*i)
        canvas.coords(planets[i], (px-size[i],py-size[i],px+size[i],py+size[i]))
    root.after(100, update_positions)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=700, height=700, bg="black")
arcs = [canvas.create_oval(350-35*i, 350-35*i, 350+35*i, 350+35*i, outline=color[i]) for i in range(len(color))]
planets = [canvas.create_oval(350, 350, 350, 350, fill=color[i]) for i in range(len(color))]
update_positions()
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note that items created on the canvas are **kept until you remove them**. If you want to change the drawing, you can either use methods like `.coords()`, `.itemconfig()`, and `.move()` to modify the items, or use `.delete()` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably draw the animation on a canvas, instead of on a static image; You can then move the elements of the animation that are modified at each step of the simulation.

Something along those lines: (press start at the bottom to start)

```
import tkinter as tk


def animate():
    canvas.move(1, 5, 0)     # 1 refers to the object to be moved ID, dx=5, dy=0
    root.update()
    root.after(50, animate)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=400)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 50, 10, 50, 50, 10, 50)  # canvas object ID created here by tkinter 

    btn = tk.Button(root, text='start', command=animate)
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```